# Does adding a ceiling improve temp?

Tags: ceiling, garage

My garage has a roof,  four walls and a door.

It currently has beams running along the ceiling height which looks like it was used for storage.

Would adding a ceiling keep my garage at a Warmer temperature for longer?

If it does what is a good and low cost material to use?

Comment: Is there any source of heat within the garage itself?

Comment: Not yet,  but there will be.

Answer (score 1):

> **Would adding a ceiling keep my garage at a Warmer temperature for longer?**

Yes, but you probably need to at least seal around the doors and perhaps insulate plain metal doors.

> **what is a good and low cost material to use?**

In my part of the world, mineral wool in rolls.

You can suspend this in netting (the upper floor of an office building I use has this, with a false ceiling below, but the insulation is suspended in netting). Stapling some netting to your beams seems to me easier than attaching drywall/plasterboard and laying insulation above that.